# unable to insert entries into another table, using after insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_addRentalCollection
AFTER INSERT ON contracts
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    v_monthly_payment_date Date := :NEW.contractStartDate;
    v_partial_payment NUMBER(9,2);
    v_monthlyRentalFee Number(9,2);

BEGIN

    SELECT monthlyRentalFee 
    INTO v_monthlyRentalFee
    FROM stalls
    WHERE stallID = :NEW.stallID;
    
    FOR payment_rec IN 1..CEIL(:NEW.contractMonths) LOOP    
        IF payment_rec = 1 THEN
            v_partial_payment := v_monthlyRentalFee * (EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(:NEW.contractStartDate)) - EXTRACT(DAY FROM :NEW.contractStartDate) + 1) / EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(:NEW.contractStartDate));
        ELSE    
            v_partial_payment := 0; 
        END IF;
        
        INSERT INTO rentalcollection VALUES ('RC' || TO_CHAR(rentalCollection_sequence.nextVal, 'FM00000'),:NEW.contractID, :NEW.renterID, :NEW.stallID, NULL, v_partial_payment + v_monthlyRentalFee, v_monthly_payment_date, 0, 'Unpaid');
                                            
        
        v_monthly_payment_date := ADD_MONTHS(:NEW.contractStartDate, payment_rec);
        
    END LOOP;

END;
/

CREATE TABLE contracts
(
    contractID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, --C00001
    renterID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    stallID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    ContractStartDate DATE,
    ContractEndDate DATE,
    contractMonths NUMBER(9,2), 
    totalContractFee NUMBER (9,2), 
    unpaidFee NUMBER (9,2),
    status VARCHAR(11),

    PRIMARY KEY (contractID, renterID, stallID),
    FOREIGN KEY (renterID) REFERENCES renters(renterID),
    FOREIGN KEY (stallID) REFERENCES stalls(stallID)
);

CREATE TABLE rentalcollection
(
    rentalCollectionID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    contractID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    renterID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    stallID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    rentalCollectionDate DATE,
    amount NUMBER(9,2),
    actualCollectionDate DATE,
    overdueFee NUMBER(9,2),
    collectionStatus VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'Unpaid', --paid or unpaid

    PRIMARY KEY (rentalCollectionID),
    FOREIGN KEY (contractID, renterID, stallID) REFERENCES contracts(contractID, renterID, stallID)
);
```

This is a after insert record to insert multiple insertion for `rentalcollection` but there is no rows inserted into `rentalcollection` table even though there are no trigger error when created.

This code is expected to insert multiple entries into `rentalcollection` table when there is 1 insert into the `contracts` table.

Comment: MySQL does not implement PL/SQL. Maybe you use OracleDB? Check `SHOW VERSION();`

Comment: It's clearly Oracle syntax, so I corrected the tags.

Comment: In order to provide a reproducible test case, you will need to share the insert statement you are using to test it with. Also, verify that you either commit afterwards or are examining the results in the *same* session as the insert. Lastly, verify that you didn't drop and recreate the contracts table after creating the trigger (you have the trigger first, which isn't possible unless the table existed already). If you do drop the table you lose the trigger. Lastly, verify that you *do* see the inserted row in contracts to prove the trigger didn't raise an exception that you simply can't see.

Comment: Please visit an online DB playground (eg https://dbfiddle.uk), create an [MCVE] and put the link to it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but there is no records inserted into rentalcollection table

That's because there's either no matching row in `stalls` table, or you entered `contractMonths` which prevent loop to run at least once.

Here's a working demo. First, tables you posted (I removed foreign key constraints to tables I don't have):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE contracts(
  2  contractID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, --C00001
  3  renterID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  4  stallID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  5  ContractStartDate DATE,
  6  ContractEndDate DATE,
  7  contractMonths NUMBER(9,2),
  8  totalContractFee NUMBER (9,2),
  9  unpaidFee NUMBER (9,2),
 10  status VARCHAR(11),
 11  PRIMARY KEY (contractID,renterID, stallID)
 12  --FOREIGN KEY (renterID) REFERENCES renters(renterID),
 13  --FOREIGN KEY (stallID) REFERENCES stalls(stallID)
 14  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE rentalcollection(
  2    rentalCollectionID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  3    contractID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  4    renterID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  5    stallID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  6    rentalCollectionDate DATE,
  7    amount NUMBER(9,2),
  8    actualCollectionDate DATE,
  9    overdueFee NUMBER(9,2),
 10    collectionStatus VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'Unpaid', --paid or unpaid
 11    PRIMARY KEY (rentalCollectionID),
 12    FOREIGN KEY (contractID, renterID, stallID) REFERENCES contracts(contractID, renterID, stallID)
 13  );

Table created.
```

Stalls table and sequence I'm missing; if I want trigger to compile, I need that one:

```
SQL> create table stalls as select 100 monthlyrentalfee, 1 stallid from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create sequence rentalCollection_sequence;

Sequence created.
```

Trigger; I didn't modify anything:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_addRentalCollection
  2  AFTER INSERT ON contracts
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4
  5  DECLARE
  6  v_monthly_payment_date Date := :NEW.contractStartDate;
  7  v_partial_payment NUMBER(9,2);
  8  v_monthlyRentalFee Number(9,2);
  9
 10  BEGIN
 11
 12      SELECT monthlyRentalFee
 13      INTO v_monthlyRentalFee
 14      FROM stalls
 15      WHERE stallID = :NEW.stallID;
 16
 17      FOR payment_rec IN 1..CEIL(:NEW.contractMonths) LOOP
 18          IF payment_rec = 1 THEN
 19              v_partial_payment := v_monthlyRentalFee * (EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(:NEW.contractStartDate)) - EXTRACT(DAY FROM :NEW.contractStartDate) + 1) / EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(:NEW.contractStartDate));
 20          ELSE
 21              v_partial_payment := 0;
 22          END IF;
 23
 24          INSERT INTO rentalcollection VALUES ('RC' || TO_CHAR(rentalCollection_sequence.nextVal, 'FM00000'),:NEW.contractID, :NEW.renterID, :NEW.stallID, NULL, v_partial_payment + v_monthlyRentalFee, v_monthly_payment_date, 0, 'Unpaid');
 25
 26
 27          v_monthly_payment_date := ADD_MONTHS(:NEW.contractStartDate, payment_rec);
 28
 29      END LOOP;
 30
 31  END;
 32  /

Trigger created.
```

OK, let's test it. Insert into `contracts`:

```
SQL> insert into contracts values
  2  ('a', 'b', '1', sysdate, sysdate + 2, 2, 1000, 300, 'x');

1 row created.
```

You expected some rows in `rentalcollection`. I have two, which means that trigger seems to be OK (if you have right data elsewhere):

```
SQL> select * From rentalcollection;

RENTALCOLLECTIO CONTRACTID RENTERID STALLID RENTALCOL     AMOUNT ACTUALCOL OVERDUEFEE COLLECTIONSTATU
--------------- ---------- -------- ------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------------
RC00001         a          b        1                     125.81 24-DEC-23          0 Unpaid
RC00002         a          b        1                        100 24-JAN-24          0 Unpaid

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works:

```sql
CREATE TABLE stalls(
  stallid VARCHAR2(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  monthlyRentalFee NUMBER(9,2)
)

INSERT INTO stalls (stallid, monthlyrentalfee) VALUES (1, 100);

CREATE TABLE contracts(
contractID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, --C00001
renterID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
stallID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ContractStartDate DATE,
ContractEndDate DATE,
contractMonths NUMBER(9,2), 
totalContractFee NUMBER (9,2), 
unpaidFee NUMBER (9,2),
status VARCHAR(11),
PRIMARY KEY (contractID,renterID, stallID),
--FOREIGN KEY (renterID) REFERENCES renters(renterID),
FOREIGN KEY (stallID) REFERENCES stalls(stallID)
);

CREATE TABLE rentalcollection(
  rentalCollectionID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  contractID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  renterID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  stallID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  rentalCollectionDate DATE,
  amount NUMBER(9,2),
  actualCollectionDate DATE,
  overdueFee NUMBER(9,2),
  collectionStatus VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'Unpaid', --paid or unpaid
  PRIMARY KEY (rentalCollectionID),
  FOREIGN KEY (contractID, renterID, stallID) REFERENCES contracts(contractID, renterID, stallID)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE rentalCollection_sequence;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_addRentalCollection
AFTER INSERT ON contracts
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    v_monthly_payment_date Date := :NEW.contractStartDate;
    v_partial_payment      rentalcollection.amount%TYPE;
    v_monthlyRentalFee     stalls.monthlyrentalfee%TYPE;

BEGIN

    SELECT monthlyRentalFee 
    INTO v_monthlyRentalFee
    FROM stalls
    WHERE stallID = :NEW.stallID;
    
    FOR payment_rec IN 1..CEIL(:NEW.contractMonths) LOOP    
        IF payment_rec = 1 THEN
            v_partial_payment := v_monthlyRentalFee * (EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(:NEW.contractStartDate)) - EXTRACT(DAY FROM :NEW.contractStartDate) + 1) / EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(:NEW.contractStartDate));
        ELSE    
            v_partial_payment := 0; 
        END IF;
        
        INSERT INTO rentalcollection VALUES ('RC' || TO_CHAR(rentalCollection_sequence.nextVal, 'FM00000'),:NEW.contractID, :NEW.renterID, :NEW.stallID, NULL, v_partial_payment + v_monthlyRentalFee, v_monthly_payment_date, 0, 'Unpaid');
                                            
        
        v_monthly_payment_date := ADD_MONTHS(:NEW.contractStartDate, payment_rec);
        
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Then if you use:

```sql
INSERT INTO contracts (
  contractid,
  renterid,
  stallid,
  contractstartdate,
  contractenddate,
  contractmonths
)
SELECT 1, 1, 1, DATE '2023-12-16', DATE '2024-01-15', 1.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 1, DATE '2023-12-16', DATE '2024-02-29', 2.5 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the table contains:

```sql
SELECT * FROM rentalcollection;
```

| RENTALCOLLECTIONID | CONTRACTID | RENTERID | STALLID | RENTALCOLLECTIONDATE | AMOUNT | ACTUALCOLLECTIONDATE | OVERDUEFEE | COLLECTIONSTATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RC00001 | 1 | 1 | 1 | *null* | 151.61 | 2023-12-16 00:00:00 | 0 | Unpaid |
| RC00002 | 1 | 1 | 1 | *null* | 100 | 2024-01-16 00:00:00 | 0 | Unpaid |
| RC00003 | 2 | 1 | 1 | *null* | 151.61 | 2023-12-16 00:00:00 | 0 | Unpaid |
| RC00004 | 2 | 1 | 1 | *null* | 100 | 2024-01-16 00:00:00 | 0 | Unpaid |
| RC00005 | 2 | 1 | 1 | *null* | 100 | 2024-02-16 00:00:00 | 0 | Unpaid |

If you want to see the data in another session (even a session belonging to the same user) then you will need to `COMMIT` that data as uncommitted data is not visible in any other session than the one it was created in.

---

You can improve the trigger by performing all the `INSERT`s in a single statement (rather than using PL/SQL loops):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_addRentalCollection
AFTER INSERT ON contracts
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  v_monthly_payment_date Date := :NEW.contractStartDate;
  v_partial_payment NUMBER(9,2);
  v_monthlyRentalFee Number(9,2);

BEGIN
  SELECT monthlyRentalFee 
  INTO v_monthlyRentalFee
  FROM stalls
  WHERE stallID = :NEW.stallID;

  INSERT INTO rentalcollection (
    rentalcollectionid,
    contractid,
    renterid,
    stallid,
    amount,
    actualCollectionDate,
    overduefee,
    collectionstatus
  )
  WITH months ( month_start, month_end, end_dt ) AS (
    SELECT :NEW.ContractStartDate,
           LEAST(
             :NEW.ContractEndDate,
             ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(:NEW.ContractStartDate, 'MM'), 1)
           ),
           :NEW.ContractEndDate + 1
    FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT month_end,
           LEAST(
             end_dt,
             ADD_MONTHS(month_end, 1)
           ),
           end_dt
    FROM   months
    WHERE  month_end < end_dt
  )
  SELECT 'RC' || TO_CHAR(rentalCollection_sequence.nextVal, 'FM00000'),
         :NEW.contractID,
         :NEW.renterID,
         :NEW.stallID,
         CASE
         WHEN month_start = :NEW.ContractStartDate
         THEN 1 + MONTHS_BETWEEN(month_end, month_start)
         ELSE 1
         END * v_monthlyRentalFee,
         month_start,
         0,
         'Unpaid'
  FROM   months;
END;
/
```

Then the same `INSERT` results in the table containing the same data.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hyH7YJf_)